# Convert list<string> to string and then back to list<string>

Tags: java, arrays, list

How do I convert a `List<String>` to a String array and back while keeping the `[` and `]`?

For example:

```
[hello, hello2, hello3]
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent serialization. If you want to serialize objects to human-readable form consider using JSON format. There are plenty of examples available on this topic.

Comment: Please write input and output of what you want to achieve (edit your post). [hello, hello2, hello3] - is input or output? For instance, I have :..... I want to get:. ......

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want correctly.

For list to string:

```
String str = Arrays.toString(list.toArray());
```

For string to list:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Made now a String with this:

```html
String result = console.stream()
                              .map(n -> String.valueOf(n))
                              .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"));
```

Later i can now replace { and } instead of [ and ], so everything works :D
Thanks anyway for the answers

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways, here is one.

```
List<String> list =
        Arrays.asList("hello", "hello2", "hello3");

String s = list.toString();
System.out.println(s);

list = Arrays.asList(s.substring(1,s.length()-1).split("\\s*,\\s*"));
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[hello, hello2, hello3]
[hello, hello2, hello3]
```

Answer (score -1):

List -> String

```
Arrays.toString(list.toArray())
```

String -> List

```
List<String> converted = Arrays.asList(str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(","));
```

Comment: Problem with this is that my List<String> contains the last few lines of a file, so with you solution i also have no brackets and the lines are in one line

Comment: @Givou What do you mean no brackets? When I test the code it includes the `[` and `]`

Comment: Huh? Okay, that was my fault, i replaced the brackets to nothing. I need this because i transmit the last 10 lines of a log through a socket. And when i convert the String back on the receiving side i get now [[Bla]blabli,blabli]

Comment: @Givou I've fixed it. If it helps, please consider accepting! :)